# Rearranging conditional probability to solve

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to find the probability $P(B' ∪ C)$, working with the information that:

$P(A) = .3$

$P(B|A) = 0.75$

$P(B|A′) = 0.20$

$P(C|A∩B) = 0.20$

$P (C|A′ ∩B) = 0.15$

$P (C|A∩B′) = 0.80$

$P(C|A′ ∩ B′) = 0.90$

I have already found $P(B) = .365$, $P(C) = .63$, and $P(A∩B∩C)=.045$.

Does anyone have any tips on how to get started finding $P(B' ∪ C)$? I have been trying to rearrange $P(A∩B∩C)$ to find something useful but to no avail.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

Your intermediate results are correct. Since

$$P(B' \cup C) = P(B') + P(C) - P(B'\cap C)$$

you  only need to calculate $P(B' \cap C)$.

But you have already done this implicitly while calculating $P(C)$ because

\begin{eqnarray*} P(B' \cap C) 
& = & P(A\cap B' \cap C) + P(A'\cap B' \cap C) \\
& = & P(C|A\cap B')P(A\cap B') + P(C|A'\cap B')P(A'\cap B') 
\end{eqnarray*}

So, you get $P(B' \cap C) = 0.564$ and, hence, $\boxed{P(B' \cup C) = 0.701}$.